# How to bind a socket receiving information on the client

Tags: c++, sockets, networking, boost-asio

All the training examples I find work on IP address 0.0.0.0 (udp::v4()). I know about white and gray IP addresses, but since the browser, online games, messengers, torrent are able to get information from outside, even though my IP address is gray. I want to understand how to implement this.

If I specify my public IP address, then when you bind the error pops up (logical, because this IP address belongs to the ISP). And I really doubt that clients change the router settings to work correctly.

Comment: browser is able to receive information from outside because it uses white IP to connect there (*"so it somehow opens publicly accessible socket"* - it does not). You should probably read about NAT.

Comment: @user7860670 Yes, I've come across the mention of NAT before, but all the material is for DevOps, and I still don't understand how to implement it

Comment: _“All the training examples I find work on 0.0.0.0 IP-adress (udp::v4()).”_ Those are **bad** examples; please avoid them. [Never bind to `0.0.0.0`.](https://superuser.com/a/1667180/769989) To listen on “any address”, bind to `::`. Your browser is not _“able to receive information from outside”_. If you are referring to NAT (_Nonsensical Addressing Trouble_), a browser can **initiate a connection** towards outside and then, thanks to a router’s ugly port (re)mapping, get responses pertaining to that connection. My strong recommendation is to [avoid IPv4 entirely](https://shorturl.at/blrW1).

Comment: @Naxel Don’t implement it; [avoid it](https://shorturl.at/blrW1). That’s my best piece of networking advice. Also, you cannot “implement” NAT; your router implements NAT. If you want your router to do the opposite (sometimes called DNAT, while the more common “endpoint-initiated” NAT is called SNAT), you need to configure static **port forwarding** on the router. Then your router will expose a “publicly accessible socket” for you (well, not quite; port forwarding works on a way lower level, in the kernel, not on a BSD sockets level) and forward connections to an “internal” machine you choose.

Comment: @AndrejPodzimek 1. *bind to `::`* - I don't understand, is this a mistake? 2. I wouldn't mind familiarizing myself with IPv6. Is implementation of IPv6 at the client and server code level sufficient to work over the Internet, would there be any problems?

Comment: @AndrejPodzimek Okay, SNAT can be useful for creating a server. But the browser, online games, messengers, and torrent don't change the router settings to get responses. I want to understand how I can implement getting information in my client

Comment: @Naxel Binding to `::` is not a mistake, it is a standard and recommended approach. BTW, IPv6 APIs give you backward IPv4 compatibility; binding to `::` matches all IPv6 _or_ IPv4 addresses. Libraries like `getaddrinfo()` support mapping of legacy IPv4 addresses into `::ffff:xxxx:xxxx` where `xxxx:xxxx` are IPv4 address bits. To get information via IPv4 without changing router settings, you need to connect to an external machine with a public IPv4 address, exactly the way browsers talk to public web servers. If you avoid IPv4 and use IPv6, then all addresses are public and the problem is gone.

Comment: Roughly: the server listens for connections on some publicly known IP address S and port P. A browser (or other client) runs on your machine M, behind a router R. When the browser wants to connect to S:P, it creates a socket, which gets bound to some random port X. The request to connect goes to the router, which creates its own socket on random port Y (not really; router works at a lower level, but bear with me for the sake of exposition) and uses that to connect to S:P. Packets now travel from M:X to R:Y to S:P, and in reverse in the other direction.

Comment: This works because, at the time the connection is established, the router remembers that packets arriving from S:P to R:Y should be forwarded to M:X. But an unsolicited packet to R:Y (or any other router port, unless configured for port forwarding) would be dropped. This is NAT in a nutshell.